# How can I resize root lvm partition?

Tags: lvm

I've tried to resize lvm root partition, but something goes wrong.
Can you explain how should I resize it?
I've added `/dev/sdb`, then I've done `sudo vgextend cl /dev/sdb`, then `sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/cl/root`

```
[user@localhost ~]$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0   20G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda2        8:2    0   19G  0 part 
  ├─cl-root 253:0    0   37G  0 lvm  /
  └─cl-swap 253:1    0    2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sdb           8:16   0   20G  0 disk 
└─cl-root   253:0    0   37G  0 lvm  /
sr0          11:0    1 1024M  0 from  

vsfomin@localhost ~]$ sudo vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               cl
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        2
  Metadata Sequence No  5
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                2
  Act PV                2
  VG Size               38.99 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              9982
  Alloc PE / Size       9982 / 38.99 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               7a7cAk-kmpk-R3os-aPtf-5JFI-F41K-At1gbW
```

Still see 17G of space. What I did wrong?

```
vsfomin@localhost ~]$ df -h
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs             1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /dev
tmpfs                1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                1.5G  9.7M  1.5G   1% /run
tmpfs                1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/cl-root   17G   17G  921M  95% /
/dev/sda1           1014M  334M  681M  33% /boot
tmpfs                299M   36K  299M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: you have to grow the filesystem, too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must extend filesystem on the extended partition:
If it ext4 then use

- resize2fs for linux extended filesystems, or
- xfs_growfs for xfs

Comment: thanks,  sudo xfs_growfs / -d resolve the issue!

Comment: @VladimirFomin please remember to use the ✔ mark to show this answer best helped you